# Delete 3D array causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, 3d, delete-operator

So I'm having trouble deleting a 3D array. It seems to cause a segmentation fault in my code. This is what I have. The segmentation fault is caused by the deletion of the 3D array, but I don't know why.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
{
  //variables
  ifstream inputFileStream[ argc - 2 ];
  int ***dimensions;

  //open inputFileStream and read in values...

  //creating the dynamic 3D array and reading in grey values
  dimensions = new int**[ argc - 2 ];
  for( int i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++ )
  {
      dimensions[ i ] = new int*[ width ];
      for( int j = 0; j < width; j++ )
      {
          dimensions[ i ][ j ] = new int[ height ];
          for( int k = 0; k < height; k++ )
          {
              inputFileStream[ i ] >> dimensions[ i ][ j ][ k ];
          }
      }
  }

  //do something with array

  //delete array
  for( int i = 0; i < width; i++ )
  {
      for( int j = 0; j < height; j++ )
      {
          delete[] dimensions[ i ][ j ];
      } 
      delete[] dimensions[ i ];        
  }
  delete[] dimensions;
}
```

Comment: What is `width`'s value?

Comment: Are you deleting the array at any other place? this can be deleting a copy of the pointer, doesn't have to be the actual `dimensions` pointer.

Comment: Im not delete the array at any other place. The value of width varies for what file you put in but it is 495 in this case

Comment: @AlexCaruso `//do something with array`  That could mean anything, including corrupting the heap.  How about do *nothing* with the array?  Does the problem still appear when nothing is done?

Comment: If I actually do nothing with the array, just create it and delete it, I still get a segmentation fault. It's definitely how I delete it, but as far as I can see, the deleting logic makes sense to me. I was hoping another set of eye's would see maybe a mistake in that I am deleting something that isn't there.

Comment: To avoid this sort of error, replace this whole thing with `vector< vector< vector<int> > > dimensions(argc - 2, vector< vector<int> >(height, vector<int>(width)));`

Comment: IDK why they made vector constructor explicit, it'd be much easier to read if `vector<vector<vector<int>>>(depth, height, width);` were allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When allocating, your 'i' value goes from 0 to 'argc-2', your 'j' value goes from 0 to 'width', and your 'k' value corresponds to 'height'. When deleting, your 'i' value goes from 0 to 'width', and your 'j' value goes from 0 to 'height'. Yet you index with [i][j] in both cases. This is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full but simplified example of code that works:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
{
    //variables
    int ***dimensions;

    //creating the dynamic 3D array and reading in grey values
    dimensions = new int**[ 10 ];
    int width = 10;
    int height = 20;
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        dimensions[ i ] = new int*[ width ];
        for( int j = 0; j < width; j++ )
            dimensions[ i ][ j ] = new int[ height ];
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < width; j++ )
            delete[] dimensions[ i ][ j ];
        delete[] dimensions[ i ];        
    }
    delete[] dimensions;
}
```

As you can see, the loops are over `10` and `width`.  The `height` plays no role in the looping logic.  So the issue is that you lost track of how to unwind the 3 dimensions, erroneously using `height` as the inner loop constraint.